# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module error on creating new app. Previosuly existing app work fine

Tags: angularjs

I get this error while trying to launch a new AngularJS app. The previous apps that is already in my workspace is working fine without any module load error. I tried creating a very simple app as shown below but even this app fails to launch with module load error.
[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lveND.png)
[javascript file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUn7D.png)

#### Stacktrace:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module mod due to:
>    Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'mod' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
>    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$injector/nomod?p0=mod
>           at

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

It is better to show what is actually happening, rather than describing what you expect to happen.

**Please include code and output as content for your question, not as pictures or external links**

Comment: you are missing JS script in HTML: `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/hello.js"></script>`

Comment: Damn it! how can i forget to include the javascipt file and expect it to work. Thanks.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts i apologize for the formatting. Still trying to get a handle of this website.

Comment: Please edit your question to **include the text for your code**.

Comment: The `type` attribute in a `<script>` tag is not necessary in HTML5. see https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp